# Why can't I assign to a string if it was previously compared to an enum?

Tags: typescript

Consider the code below.  If you run it in the [TypeScript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=24&ssc=6&pln=1&pc=1#code/AQ4UwOwVwW2B1AlgEwOZgC4GdgG8BQowAwgPYwAOAhgE5UBGANmABLlgDKVzOAvMAHIylWg2ZsYnbmCwCANIVAAFGogDGrRFgykaAT2D8BK9Zu269AxSAC%20%20a8DWMqWHEjSYAIjLWqKGRFIIPAciClUANyoMMGAIKkkALgQUdGwAbnsiIjUg7RooNR0aAAp4pJSPbABKEOz64AwACy0AOnLY-g7MhuA7UNA04AA5BLAS6uT3NJwCXqIaTCgaYOa27oHbB36iAHpdx1JkWMRKZkkIDGjAiAdmDGAAd1SvHz8AoKmXjG8sX0R-DdDHEwI9Kmlfv9AUEStNMFhWsJqHQmKx2FweNUeqB7k9vqMKvlEBBUMDnlVIe8bq0CWBMg5EAAzYAlclpWmGfhw7CI8jIsRoyQYmS1OYNNmYDkAaiMAEFkMgOOw1iSBNitvZ8EA), line `widgetName += 'AddSomething'` errors out with `Type 'string' cannot be assigned to type 'Widgets'`.

However, if I cast the enum on the previous line to string (`widgetName == <string> Widgets.ComparableHomeSales`, everything compiles fine.

Why is that?

```
enum Widgets {
    ComparableHomeSales = 'ComparableHomeSales',
    PriceHistory = 'PriceHistory'
}

class WidgetDescription {
    private name: Widgets;

    constructor(name: Widgets) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    get Name(): Widgets {
        return this.name;
    }
}

// code implementation
let widgetDescription: WidgetDescription = new WidgetDescription(Widgets.ComparableHomeSales);
let widgetName: string = widgetDescription.Name;

if (widgetName == Widgets.ComparableHomeSales) {
    widgetName += 'AddSomething'; // <-- ERROR
}
```

P.S. Looks like a bug.  I opened an [issue](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/35824).

Comment: Interesting that `widgetName = widgetName + 'AddSomething';` doesn't give the same error.

Comment: It is because 'AddSomething' is not part of enum values. Only `'ComparableHomeSales'` and `'PriceHistory'` are valid strings

Comment: @AlexanderVidaurreArroyo But `widgetName` is declared as type `string`, and the concatenation does result in a string. There is no reason it should be a type error, and the version with `+` instead of `+=` has no type error.

Comment: It seems like a Typescript bug. I'm not able to find any existing bug reports about it on the issue tracker, but it's hard to search for because you can't search for `+=` on GitHub. https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues

Comment: The problem is not with `+=`, type of `widgetName` inside of `if` clause refined to `Widgets`. Not sure if it is by design or not. [Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/KYOwrgtgBAYg9nKBvAUFdUCGUC8UDkm+ANGhgEa4Hn4oC+KKANsAC5YBcUAzqwE4BLEAHMq+WigEAzKAApsORbAQA6TAEpkZdNgD0urFBCY+fOAHdgAEyitE8OGvoogA)

Comment: @AlekseyL. Why does `widgetName = widgetName + 'AddSomething';` work then?

Comment: @AngryHacker interesting, indeed looks like a bug

Comment: This behavior is very close to discriminated unions. if condition `widgetName == Widgets.ComparableHomeSales` is true, TS knows, that `widgetName` is *exactly* `Widgets.ComparableHomeSales` and nothing else. So it apply restrictions, based on `Widgets.ComparableHomeSales` type